# multi directional scrolling site

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, scroll

Ive been asked if i am able to program a multi directional scrolling site like this- [COS](http://www.cosstores.com/gb/site/home__start.nhtml) only using wordpress. Initially i thought i may be flash but the source seems like it could be simple, possibly with elements of jquery. . . . .

I am unable to find any themes that even come close to it. And initially i wanted to know how it has been achieved to see if i am able to start the design work

any ideas how this has been achieved. More to the point if the multi scrolling could be applied on wordpress

Comment: As with your last question, this is a HTML and CSS issue. You need to use those tags if you want to attract the right audience. Retagging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how likely it will be that you would find a wordpress theme that suits your needs with this effect, but I can tell you that jQuery has a great plugin called scrollTo that achieves this effect with ease.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/