# Web Designing: Navigatible Large Flash Background

Tags: html, css, flash, background, flashdevelop

I'm working on a project and I want to make one big background where only a portion of it is showing at a time, but when the user clicks a menu item the screen scrolls to a different section of the large background. There will be another menu on the second area that will move the background somewhere else. How do I do that?

Actually I've to create a website similar to this one

```
http://artofflightmovie.com/
```

I am confused that

1)what are requirements for designing such a website. (javascript? flash? ??)

2)how we generally name such kind of website?

3)How can I find such sample websites (what should I search on google)

If you can explain a little bit that how such website will be designed(Just Basics) I'll be very grateful to you.

Each, any and every kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not flash - It's jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

1) Fairly certain as tuxtimo said, definitely no flash there. So, yes, JavaScript/jQuery is good enough (if not better) for the job.
Probably there are many out there, however, I've seen this one before:

http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ The site itself is a very basic example of what you might be looking for. And it has documentation - https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath. Figured it's a good starting point.

Also check out [multi directional scrolling site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633909/multi-directional-scrolling-site) - the http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ might also be what you need.

Also another one I found - http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/ and this one has a demo that does pretty much does it all like you want: http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/examples/svgtree/index.html

2/3) I'm not sure on this, however one/single [multi-directional] scroll page seems to yield some results for me, give it a shot :)